# github pages same repository for two different subdomains

Tags: github-pages

I have a repository with two branches: dev and master.

My custom domain (https://example.com) is already registered and have my test branch already linked under https://test.example.com.

My question is: How can I bind master branch to https://master.example.com subdomain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I would like to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately such thing is not possible on github pages.

There is a workaround tho:

- Create a secondary github account
- Host your site under test.example.com

You will need to swap github users tho, which can be a bit annoying.